# Run an Installer class during set up using Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to run an [`Installer` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) during the set-up of a Windows desktop application. The point of the installer is to encrypt the configuration settings for the application using the `DataProtectionConfigurationProvider` (this must take place on the user's machine).

Executing custom actions seems quite straightforward in the old vdproj projects, but we prefer to use Inno Setup since it works really well and goes nicely in our build environment.

I've looked at the documentation around running other executables etc after the install process but do not see anything that refers to running an `Installer` class within the application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a .NET code directly from InnoSetup.

Either build a small application that you embed to the installer, extract to a temporary folder during installation and run it.

Or build a .dll and call it from InnoSetup.
See [Call C# DLL from Inno Setup with callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27549823/850848)